# installing xampp on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

downloaded and installed XAMPP from the internet.

But there is a problem:
-during installation, the wizard asked me if I would like to install Apache and MySQL as services. I choosed both. The rest of the installation went ok, but when it started the xampp console error message appeared:
"Ports 80 or 443 (SSL) already in use! Installing Apache2-2 service failed!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another webserver running on your computer, something listening on port 80/443. My guess is that you have IIS running.

Comment: @Bas-i have uninstalled the IIS..